# I cannot figure out this exception and how to fix this

Tags: c++, exception, c++-winrt, winui-3

I am getting this exception for my project and I cannot figure out what it is. It is in  winui3 project using c++/winrt and xaml. Here is some code from a project were I isolated the exception. I have also commented out some prior attempts at solving the problem.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Core.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.System.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#endif

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: ``http://aka.ms/winui-project-info``.

namespace winrt::OpenCVTestingSDK::implementation
{

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

int32_t MainWindow::MyProperty()
{
    throw hresult_not_implemented();
}

void MainWindow::MyProperty(int32_t /* value */)
{
    throw hresult_not_implemented();
}

void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    
   
    Mat picture_data = Mat(250, 100, CV_8UC3, Scalar(250, 0, 75));

    
    TCHAR mypicturespath[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_MYPICTURES, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, mypicturespath);

    wstring imagePathW = mypicturespath;
    string imagePath(imagePathW.begin(), imagePathW.end());

    bool imageCreated = cv::imwrite(imagePath + "\\CrazyImageName.png", picture_data);

    
    if (imageCreated) {
        myButton().Content(box_value(L"True"));
    }
    else {
        myButton().Content(box_value(L"False"));
    }
    
    //list<string> testListContents;

    //testListContents.push_back("test1");
    //testListContents.push_back("test2");
    //testListContents.push_back("test3");

    //testList().Items().Append(box_value(L"test1"));
    //testList().Items().Append(box_value(L"test2"));
    //testList().Items().Append(box_value(L"test2"));

    
    
    
    //hstring message = L"Hello developers!";

    //co_await winrt::resume_foreground(testList.Dispatcher());
    //testList().Items().Append(box_value(message));

    // Switch to the foreground thread associated with textblock.
    //co_await winrt::resume_foreground(testList.Dispatcher());

    //winrt::init_apartment();

    //auto processOp{ DoWorkAsync() };
    
    //winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListView testList

    testList().Items().Append(box_value(L"test1"));
}

//winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainWindow::DoWorkAsync() {
    //winrt::apartment_context ui_thread;
    //co_await resume_background();

    //co_await ui_thread;
    //testList().Items().Append(box_value(L"test1")); 
//}

void MainWindow::testList_SelectionChanged(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs const& args)
{



}

}
```

Xaml

```
<Window 
x:Class="OpenCVTestingSDK.MainWindow"
xmlns="``http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation``"
xmlns:x="``http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml``"
xmlns:local="using:OpenCVTestingSDK"
xmlns:d="``http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008``"
xmlns:mc="``http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006``"
mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="40, 0, 40, 30">
        
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    
    
        <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="25, 0, 25, 0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="subsystemPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Header}">Aircraft System</TextBlock>
                <ListView x:Name="testList"  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="testList_SelectionChanged" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    
    </Grid>

     </Window>
```

xaml.h

```
#pragma once 

#include "MainWindow.g.h"

namespace winrt::OpenCVTestingSDK::implementation
{
struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow>
{
MainWindow();

        int32_t MyProperty();
        void MyProperty(int32_t value);
    
        void myButton_Click(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);
        void testList_SelectionChanged(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs const& args);
    
        //winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction DoWorkAsync();
    };

}

namespace winrt::OpenCVTestingSDK::factory_implementation
{
struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow, implementation::MainWindow>
{
};
}
```

the exception: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCF3784F69 in OpenCVTestingSDK.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x000000B32B4FDE58.

result value: 0x802b000a

Comment: When you ran it under the excellent debugger that ms makes, which line was causing the issue?

Comment: the obvious thing is that you are not testing the result of the ShGetFolderPath

Comment: Visual Studio has an outstanding debugger. Use it to step through your code to find out where exactly the exception is being thrown, which will give you a chance to figure out what's causing it to be thrown. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is an excellent time to start learning. There's no better tool available to a programmer than the debugger, and it's never too early to start using it.

Comment: It happens when the InitializeComponent() function is called in the mainWindow.xaml.cpp file. When I step into it I spend 15 mins stepping through code from Microsoft and cannot find what part of my code is causing it.

Comment: You'll need to learn how to use a debugger then. You don't have to single-step through your code only to find where an exception is thrown. Simply set up your debugger to break when any given exception is thrown. The debugger will then take you to the *exact* location the exception gets thrown. Other than that you also have the error code: `0x802b000a`. The facility code (`0x2b` or 43) is `FACILITY_XAML`, so something in your XAML code or the corresponding C++ code is off. If you feel like you're being let down, let Microsoft know that their IDE support for C++/WinRT sucks.

Comment: Does the style with the name "Header" you use in the TextBlock exist with that name?